# Bottom and side captions in floatrow

Tags: captions, floatrow

I adapted some code I found on here for vertical captions in a figure (I've also set up an [Overleaf project](https://www.overleaf.com/read/fhzryvjdxfgs) with this code for testing purposes):

```
\documentclass{FRIteza}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesideposition={left,center}}

\newlength{\colwidth}
\newlength{\rowheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \floatsetup[subfigure]{capbesidewidth=12mm}
    \setlength{\colwidth}{.4\linewidth}
    \setlength{\rowheight}{.75\colwidth}
    \centering
    \ffigbox{%
        \begin{subfloatrow}
            \fcapside[\FBwidth]
            {\caption{Image AB}\label{fig:figurea}}%
            {\hfill\null%
                \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-a}\hfill%
                \includegraphics[width=1.5\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-b}\hfill\null%
            }
        \end{subfloatrow}
        \begin{subfloatrow}
          \fcapside[\FBwidth]
            {\caption{Image C}\label{fig:figureb}}%
            {\hfill\null%
                \includegraphics[width=\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c}\hfill%
                \includegraphics[width=1.5\colwidth,height=\rowheight]{example-image-c}\hfill\null%
            }
        \end{subfloatrow}
    }%
    {\caption{This is the caption of the entire figure, describing what the figure as a whole is showing in detail and giving an overall picture of the figure's purpose.}\label{fig:figure}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This places the side captions OK:

[image]

However, I would also like to have captions at the bottom (ideally ones that can be referenced normally using `\ref` or `\cref`), like so:

[image]

It doesn't really matter what symbols are used for the captions.

I've tried two different solutions using `minipages` inside a `subfloatrow` but they cause errors in the compilation:

```
\begin{subfloatrow}
  \fcapside[\FBwidth]
    {}%
    {\hfill\null%
        \begin{minipage}{\colwidth}
            \caption{Smaller images}
            \label{fig:figuresmall}
        \end{minipage}\hfill%
        \begin{minipage}
            \caption{Larger images}
            \label{fig:figurelarge}
        \end{minipage}\hfill\null%
    }
\end{subfloatrow}
```

and

```
\begin{subfloatrow}
    \hfill\null%
    \begin{minipage}{\colwidth}
        \caption{Smaller images}
        \label{fig:figuresmall}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}
        \caption{Larger images}
        \label{fig:figurelarge}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\null%
\end{subfloatrow}
```

Is this doable using `floatrow`?